# android scheduler doesn't start

Tags: java, android, service

i have this code inside in a service. but scheduler doesn't start! whats wrong with this? I want this service to show a toast every three seconds even if the application is in the background...

```
public class notifService extends Service {
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, notifService.class);


    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf("a"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }, 3, 3, SECONDS);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `onStart(Intent,int)` method is deprecated for the Service object.

You should instead be overriding the

`onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` and then return START_STICKY.  This will ensure that your service gets restarted if it is ever killed by the os.

Secondly, you should pass the Service's context to the toast builder (you can use the `this` keyword).

Lastly, I am not sure what your intentions are, but this will most likely always be showing a toast since you are constructing it with the `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` constant.

If it is still not working, post the code you are using to start the service...

Comment: you know, this code works but i changed something and now doesn't work! but i don't know where is the wrong!!

Comment: Well you should still not be using the onStart() method.. it has been deprecated a long time.. What did you change then?

Comment: i dont know what i changed but my code worked perfectly a few minutes ago...  can you give me a complete example of what you say? please :)

Comment: well I really don't know what you tell you.. Did you switch devices you were testing on? You are going to have to try and figure out what code you changed to determine what happened. Try debugging

Comment: my main problem is not service itself, because when i put my toast under onStart it works... my problem is with my scheduler...
when i put something inside public void run() {... it doesnt run...

Comment: Is there a reason you are declaring the scheduler as final?

Comment: no, but when i change it to non final, my problem still there...
is there any way to run a code in every specific time?

Comment: Then you need to walk through with a debugger and take a look at what is happening with each of the objects